# Rails localtime returns wrong time zone

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

I have a problem where when saving a datetime attribute, the form returns -04:00 instead of -05:00

Using Rails 3.2.3

In application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Using MySQL with mysql2 adapter

Running `@wine.released_at.localtime` returns `2008-05-15 00:00:00.000000000 -04:00`
Running `@wine.released_at` returns `2008-05-15 04:00:00.000000000 Z`
Running `Time.now.zone` returns `Eastern Standard Time`
Running `@wine.released_at.zone` returns `EDT`

I'm fairly confused. I though setting config.time_zone should make it such that Rails automatically converts all database datetime values to the set time_zone...why isn't this happening?

Comment: I do have that enabled on both systems...are you saying that on the next DST switch I should start seeing -05:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if the `zone` property returns the name of the "zone interval" which is applicable for the specified time. So for a summer time it will return "EDT" but for a winter time it will return "Easter Standard Time". (It's odd that it uses an abbreviation for one but not the other, but hey...)

So it *is* using the same time zone for both - those are just different aspects within the same time zone: sometimes it's standard time, sometimes it's daylight saving time.

If you print `Time.now.localtime` it should show you a -05:00 to show that the current offset from UTC in Eastern Time is -5 hours (i.e. Eastern Time is currently 5 hours behind UTC).

Comment: So is there a way to have my form always display EST instead of EDT? Or perhaps include the "EST"/"EDT"?

Comment: @JakeTheSnake: You absolutely do *not* want to always display the EST version. You could always display `time.zone` as well as `time`. I would personally *not* use a fixed time zone throughout the system, instead allowing the user to select their local time zone, but that's a different design decision.

Comment: Well what I'm getting at is that the appearance of "-04:00" is disconcerting. Yes, the displayed time should be accurate to the user's time zone but if they see "-04:00" they might think that the time they saved didn't save correctly. i.e., I saved a date of "Jan 1, 2013" but I see "Dec 31, 2012" instead on the form. People just aren't good at recognizing and converting time zones.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake: So you should go through whatever Ruby or Rails have for custom date/time formatting - presumably to show the local time, potentially with the time zone part as well. But it really *is* using the time zone you've asked it to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using in_time_zone?

Comment: Yes, but they all return the same "Z" value (see initial post)